# Why is Flask not configuring certain environment variables from the config class? Need help understanding config process

Tags: python, flask, config

My app appears to be perfectly capable of configuring based on the `.env` file, the imported config classes, and defining variables directly. However, `FLASK_DEBUG` is failing to change depending on how I define the variables.

I should probably note that I'm using Visual Studio Code on windows. I've been told I need to use Linux or really anything but windows, and I intend to, but it's not an option right now so any help understanding how this functions with the system I have and how to navigate this would be much appreciated.

config.py:

```
import os
basedir = os.path.abspath(os.path.dirname(__file__))

class DevelopmentConfig(object):
    os.environ['SECRET_KEY'] = b'something'
    os.environ['SQLALCHEMY_DATABASE_URI'] = os.environ.get('DATABASE_URL') or \
        'sqlite:///' + os.path.join(basedir, 'app.db')
    os.environ['SQLALCHEMY_TRACK_MODIFICATIONS'] = 'False'
    os.environ['FLASK_DEBUG'] = '1'
    os.environ['DEV_DICT'] = 'dev_config_class_environ_dictionary_activated_and_working'

class ProductionConfig(object):
    os.environ['SECRET_KEY'] = os.environ.get('SECRET_KEY')
    os.environ['SQLALCHEMY_DATABASE_URI'] = os.environ.get('PRODUCTION_DATABASE_URI')
    os.environ['SQLALCHEMY_TRACK_MODIFICATION'] = 'False'
    os.environ['FLASK_DEBUG'] = '0'
    os.environ['PROD_DICT'] = 'prod_config_class_environ_dictionary_activated_and_working'
```

init.py:

```
from flask import Flask
from config import DevelopmentConfig, ProductionConfig
from flask_migrate import Migrate
from flask_sqlalchemy import SQLAlchemy
from dotenv import load_dotenv, find_dotenv
import os

app = Flask(__name__)
db = SQLAlchemy(app)
migrate = Migrate(app, db)

load_dotenv(find_dotenv())

if os.environ.get('FLASK_ENV') == 'development':
    print("Environment is development")
    app.config.from_object(DevelopmentConfig)
elif os.environ.get('FLASK_ENV') == 'production':
    print("Environment is production")
    app.config.from_object(ProductionConfig)

print(os.environ.get('TEST_DOTENV'))   #This value is stored in .env
print(os.environ.get('DEV_DICT'))      #defined in class DevelopmentConfig as os.environ['DEV_DIVT']
print(os.environ.get('PROD_DICT'))     #same but in the ProductionConfig class
print(os.environ.get('FLASK_ENV'))     #defined differently in both classes and CONFIGS CORRECTLY
print(os.environ.get('FLASK_DEBUG'))   #defined differently in both classes and DOES NOT CONFIG CORRECTLY
```

.env:

```
FLASK_ENV=development
FLASK_APP=run.py
SECRET_KEY=b'something'
PRODUCTION_DATABASE_URI='something_else'
TEST_DOTENV=config_from_dotenv_is_working   #prints correctly to command line, as do other variables defined here
```

When I run the app:

```
(flaskvenv) PS C:\Users\peter\Desktop\Projects\Social Work Site\sw_app> flask run
 * Serving Flask app "run.py" (lazy loading)
 * Environment: development
 * Debug mode: on
 * Restarting with stat
c:\...__init__.py:814: UserWarning: Neither SQLALCHEMY_DATABASE_URI nor SQLALCHEMY_BINDS is set. Defaulting SQLALCHEMY_DATABASE_URI to "sqlite:///:memory:".
  'Neither SQLALCHEMY_DATABASE_URI nor SQLALCHEMY_BINDS is set. '
c:\...__init__.py:835: FSADeprecationWarning: SQLALCHEMY_TRACK_MODIFICATIONS adds significant overhead... 

Environment is development                                     #changes correctly if I change it in .env
config_from_dotenv_is_working                                  #further proof .env works fine
dev_config_class_environ_dictionary_activated_and_working      #prints regardless of which class gets called
prod_config_class_environ_dictionary_activated_and_working     #also prints regardless of which class gets called
development                                                    #changes to production properly if I change it in .env
0                                       #stubbornly stays set to 0 regardless of it being set in config

 * Running on http://127.0.0.1:5000/ (Press CTRL+C to quit)
```

Here's the strange part:

When I defined `FLASK_DEBUG` in the `.env` file, the command line displays it properly in the automatic output, e.g. as `* Debug mode: off` or `* Debug mode: on` depending on if I set it to `0` or `1` respectively.

BUT when I call it with `os.environ.get('FLASK_DEBUG')`, it displays as 0 regardless of what I do.

Based on this, I have a few questions.

The main one and the essence of the problem is of course:

1. Why is Flask not configuring `FLASK_DEBUG` but other variables are configuring fine?

Other questions that I suspect might have some kind of connection and would help me understand this:

2. What role does the Windows OS play in this problem?
3. Why are both config classes configuring environment variables if I'm only calling one of them?
4. Why if the automatic output tells me that `Debug mode` is `on` does `os.environ.get('FLASK_DEBUG')` still return `0`?

I can solve this by defining `FLASK_ENV` in `.env`, but I want to understand how it works. The discrepancy in how things config makes me feel uneasy with not knowing how or why things function the way they do.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are mixing up the concepts of configuration classes and environment variables.

### Explanation of your result

If you define two classes and immediately in those definitions set environment variables, both of them will be run immediately. Don't do this:

```
# config.py
import os

class DevelopmentConfig(object):
    os.environ['FLASK_DEBUG'] = '1'

class ProductionConfig(object):
    os.environ['FLASK_DEBUG'] = '0'

print('FLASK_DEBUG is', os.environ['FLASK_DEBUG'])
```

After running this code, both classes will have set the env. variable, and since 0 is the last value to be set, the result will be 0:

```
$ python config.py
FLASK_DEBUG is 0
```

This is the reason your `FLASK_DEBUG` is always 0. All of your code inside `DevelopmentConfig`and `ProductionConfig` is being run no matter what is set in your `.env` file. Your problem is not related to Windows.

Besides the classes, your are also setting environment variables from you `.env` file, including `FLASK_ENV=development`. This is a variable recognized by Flask, that will turn on debug mode. This the reason debug mode is on in Flask.

### One solution: Use environment specific config classes

Define values in classes:

```
class DevelopmentConfig(object):
    MY_VARIABLE = 'dev value'
    ...

class ProductionConfig(object):
    MY_VARIABLE = 'prod value'
    ...
```

Then set the environment in an environment variable. This can be done directly in the OS, or you can use an .env file if you like:

```
FLASK_ENV=development
```

On your production server, you would create a different .env file:

```
FLASK_ENV=production
```

Then load the relevant class in Flask:

```
from dotenv import load_dotenv, find_dotenv
from flask import Flask
import os

load_dotenv(find_dotenv())    
app = Flask(__name__)
config = ProductionConfig() if os.environ.get('FLASK_ENV') == 'production' else DevelopmentConfig()
app.config.from_object(config)
print(app.config['MY_VARIABLE'])
```

You don't even need to set `FLASK_DEBUG` in this case because Flask will set it automatically based on `FLASK_ENV`.

### Other solutions

You can also ditch the config classes completely and instead import all values from environment variables or from configuration files. Read the [Flask config guide](https://flask.palletsprojects.com/en/1.1.x/config/) for more details.

Comment: Thanks, Anders! That makes sense. The reason why I started defining my environment variables in the config classes (incorrectly I now realize) is that when I define them as variables they don't work. The test variables in the config classes (`DEV_DICT` and `PROD_DICT`) print `None` when I defined them like: `SECRET_KEY=b'something'`. I'm going to accept your answer because it solved the immiediate problem and ask another question, but any other advice on why that might be from what you see above?

Comment: If you define a class `class DevelopmentConfig:` with a class variable `SECRET_KEY=b'something'`, calling `DevelopmentConfig().SECRET_KEY` does not return None

Comment: Hmm, I must have messed something up, because it is working now. Well, good. Thanks again!